# Java Eclipse: Running a program with a file argument and external JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I'm trying to run the following script:  https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/15uf/UF.java

To do so I have:

1) Opened Eclipse, made a new project named UF, and created a new class named UF, and inside of that class I've pasted the code from the above link.

2) By the instructions on their website, I saved their JAR file under

```
/usr/local/algs4/algs4.jar
```

3) Right-clicked the project, went to Properties, and under the Libraries tab there are two field options, Modulepath and Classpath.  With Modulepath highlighted I clicked Add External JARs and navigated to the location of algs4.jar.  Then I did the same for Classpath because I figure one of these must be right.

4) This file is intended for input to the program:  https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/15uf/tinyUF.txt

So I saved this under `~/Documents`.

5) Under the Run option I selected Run Configurations, clicked the Arguments tab, and typed `/home/me/Documents/tinyUF.txt`.

6) Now when I run the program nothing happens, by which I mean it shows absolutely no indication of running with the only exception being that when I hoover the mouse over the Run button it says "Run (already running)".

7) So just for testing purposes I inserted at the first line of the main function `System.out.println("TEST");` and this time when I run it, it shows the console at the bottom of Eclipse and prints TEST.

8) If I move the `System.out.println("TEST");` line down one line so that `int n = StdIn.readInt();` runs first, then the console will show but nothing prints and the program never halts.

Any thoughts about what's happening?

[Edit: I suppose I should note that I'm running Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2) on Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon.  When I followed the instructions to install Eclipse they seemed kind of strange, but I followed them anyway:  It instructed me to make the folder `/root/eclipse` and install to that folder, so I did.]

[Update: After conversation with a commenter, I found that I had to add the input file path to the launch configuration.  Now that I've done that, the program correctly reads in the txt file and outputs the correct result except that it never prints the final line and never terminates the program.  Look at the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = StdIn.readInt();
        UF uf = new UF(n);
        while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
            int p = StdIn.readInt();
            int q = StdIn.readInt();
            if (uf.connected(p, q)) continue;
            uf.union(p, q);
            StdOut.println(p + " " + q);
        }
        StdOut.println(uf.count() + " components");
    }
```

The behavior when the code is run is that it successfully completes the while loop but never reaches the line `StdOut.print]ln(uf.count() + " components");`.

Comment: Have you run your code under debugger yet? What happens if you enter some number from the keyboard while your program is waiting?

Comment: @PM77-1 I'm guessing "debugger" means under Run going to Debug.  I tried it and the console shows that it's running but it never terminates.  If I run it and enter 1 it prints TEST, then I enter 2 and it prints B (I also inserted `System.out.println("B");` just inside the while loop, forgot to mention that), then if I enter 4 it throws an exception because presumably I'm entering numbers the program can't make sense of.  So I take it the answer here is that it's not correctly reading the input text file.

Comment: Follow [this tutorial](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/june/article1.php) to set up *break points* and follow further instructions for step-by-step debugging..

Comment: Need to see your `StdIn` class.

Comment: @PM77-1 I'm not sure how to find the source files, but this page seems to have the javadocs and .jar files for it:  https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/

Comment: Where in the code do you *re-direct* your input to the file?  Where do you actually use your argument (file path)?

Comment: @PM77-1 I'm not exactly sure, I didn't write the file.  I'm trying to run it in order to understand it, but my guess is that StdIn does this somehow.  The code and the jar files are all intended to be downloaded and run as you read through the textbook.

Comment: `StdIn` reads **exclusively** from standard input, which is keyboard unless redirected.

Comment: I should perhaps note that I managed to get this to work and obtained the intended output by running it from the terminal.  However, when I did it that way, it was stored in a package named `edu.princeton.cs.algs4`.  I made this file hierarchy to match the package name, navigated to the source file, and ran `javac -cp .:/usr/local/algs4/algs4.jar edu.princeton.cs.algs4.UF < /home/me/Documents/tinyUF.txt` and it gave the correct output.

Comment: @PM77-1 So is the upshot that a file cannot be passed as an argument in this way, in Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, the file name absolutely can be passed as an argument.  I just did not see you reading and using it anywhere.

Comment: Further note, as I tried to get this to work in Eclipse, I removed the package declaration because it seemed to be causing some kind of conflict, and so I instead just include the import line `import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.*`.

Comment: @PM77-1 So then I'm not understanding--if it worked in the terminal, and the file can be passed as an argument in Eclipse, then why isn't it doing that?

Comment: Argument is being passed to your `main()` method as an array of strings.  That's what `String[] args` is for, I did not see `args` actually used in your code.  Have I missed something?

Comment: @PM77-1 I don't know, but I know that the code works in the terminal without keyboard input.  So somehow it must use the file input, although I couldn't tell you how it does that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162041/discussion-between-pm-77-1-and-addem).

Answer (score 0):

By default, the eclipse root directory is the base directory of a project. So if you're running in debug mode here, your argument would need to include the absolute path (beginning with the drive number), for example `C:/usr/local/algs4/algs4.jar` OR you would need to have the file in the same folder that the program is running from.

Just giving `/home/me/Documents/tinyUF.txt` tells the program to drill down from where it's currently at, looking for the home directory, me directory.. etc.

It's always more direct and *safer* to give the absolute path. If the path is going to be changing/dynamic, allow the jar to take in an argument. Do a check on the argument in your main() and set this as an `File inputFile = arg[0]`variable and then handle the file that way.

Comment: I think you may be assuming that I'm using a Windows computer.  I'm running Linux Mint so, if I understand correctly, `/home/...` in fact gives the absolute path from the root directory.

Comment: I've never heard of exporting a jar as a runnable, but it may not be necessary, because in conversation with a commenter, I made some progress.  It turns out that, to pass a file in as input to a program, you have to give the path to the launch configuration.  After doing that, the program almost works, it reads in the file and outputs much of the correct information.  However, when it exits the while loop, it never runs the code that comes after the while loop.

Comment: Glad you were able to make some progress. For the early exit issue, do you want to condense and share that section of code?

Comment: You mean the while loop and surrounding code?  Sure, I'll include it in the main post.